# client can not connect to server after some connections (python)

Tags: python, server

i write a server in python and it works. it can send and receive data to/from a client. every time i change this code syntax and want to execute it, i change the port number(add 1 to the previous number). and after 4 or five times changing the port number the client can't connect to the server and it gets TCP connection timeout error, although the port is usable from the server. i use Hercules as a client. the problem doesn't really dependent to the times that i change the port number. if it takes a little time that the server waits or uses on listening (i don't know how much that time is), i have the same problem and client can't connect to the server even i change port number. while client shows TCP connection timeout error server shows this error in the terminal:

```
urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://api.mycroft.ai:443 "GET 
/v1/device/0bcdba9f-4a90-4fdf-977a-61eb54afea9c/skill HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

and this is the server code that i use:

```
class server(object):
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = get_ip.get_ip_address('wlan0')  #'192.168.1.102'
    self.port = 1924
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

def listen(self,after_idle_sec, interval_sec, max_fails):
    m = self.sock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE)
    if(m ==0):
        print("SOCKET KEEPALIVE OFF, TURNING ON")
        self.set_keepalive_osx(after_idle_sec, interval_sec, max_fails)
        print("interval_sec:", interval_sec)
        print("after_idle_sec:", after_idle_sec)
        print("max_fails:", max_fails)
    else:
        print("SOCKET KEEPALIVE IS ALREADY ON")
    self.sock.listen(5)

    print('WAITING FOR A CONNECTION')

    while True:
        client, address = self.sock.accept()

        #client.settimeout(60)
        Thread(target = self.client_thread, args = (client,address)).start()

def set_keepalive_osx(self, after_idle_sec=1, interval_sec=3, max_fails=5):
    """Set TCP keepalive on an open socket.

    sends a keepalive ping once every 3 seconds (interval_sec)
    """
    # scraped from /usr/include, not exported by python's socket module
    TCP_KEEPALIVE = 0x10
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, after_idle_sec)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, interval_sec)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, max_fails)  

def shutdown(self):   #terminate server
    self.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)  #further sends and receives are disallowed
    self.sock.close()
    print ("closed")
```

def client_thread(self, client, address):

```
    while True:
        size = 1024
        try:
            self.servermsg = client.recv(size)  
            print("data received from client is: {}".format(self.servermsg))

            if self.servermsg:
                # Set the response to echo back the recieved data
                response = self.servermsg  
                #do something

             else:       
                #raise error('Client disconnected')
                raise Exception('Client disconnected')

        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
            client.close()
            return False
```

this is not exactly my code and i delete some of its method.
i thought it may relate to the `setttimeout(60)` but after i comment it i have the same problem. and i should reboot the system and after each reboot i face this problem. after i add "set_keepalive_osx" method i get this error:

```
 in set_keepalive_osx
self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, after_idle_sec)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'TCP_KEEPIDLE'
```

i change the `listen` method and call 'set_keepalive_osx' method in it. after that i dont have the error above but i don't know does it work or not. it doesnt send timeout error if i dont use it for a few minutes and also when a client disconnects it gives this error:

```
ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

instead of rising an exception that says `client disconnected`. could someone tall me what the problem is?

Comment: it only shows "waiting for a connection " and doesn't show anything while i try to connect to it with a client. at least client shows TCP connection error but server doesn't show anything and only waits. how can i trouble shoot that? i put try except in listen method but i doesn't print any error or exception.

Comment: i edit my question by adding "set_keepalive_osx " method to my code. i thought the problem could be because of TCP idle time when transmission doesn't exist between server and client. i use rasbian strectch os. could some one help me with errors and tell me if adding this method could solve the problem or not?

Comment: Do you get `Client disconnected` messages in the server ? I suspect the problem is sockets aren't properly closed, and you hit the `listen(5)` connection concurrency limit. Try to investigate problems related to ending connection

Comment: @Arthur Havlicek yes i get `client disconnected` when client disconnect or when received buffer is empty. i try with `listen(2)` and connect with port numbers from 1990 to 1998 (i could connect more and i try them one after another).i reboot the system and do another test with `listen(2)` and i start server and wait for 15 minutes then the result is i can connect with "simple tcp client tester " to server but i can't connect with "tcp client of hercules" to server. do you know why? i want server to run for two days so i need tcp keep alive because tcp idle time is 2 houres.

Comment: i also add a shutdown method but i don't know when should i call? it to make server work for 2 days

Comment: Mac OS doesn't have `TCP_KEEP*` properties. Its likely `set_keepalive_osx` cannot operate. Since you have `SOCK_REUSEADDR` normally you don't have to change port/wait between launches. If you can connect with normal tcp client such as Linux netcat but not with Hercules client, I suppose the problem is client side. Don't also forget the possibility you simply have an unreliable network, since you are on wifi.

Comment: @Arthur Havliceki have 3 question and i'd be glad if you answer them. first if suppose the problem is at the client side how should i make this connection update because a TCP connection has 2 hours timeout.

Comment: @Arthur Havlicek second i use rasbian stretch OS which is linux and the method `set_keepalive_osx` which i use is for Linux, how should i make it work according to first question i asked i need something to update the connection. and third is how should i tell server to call `shutdown ` method after a specific time like 2 days? thank you.